# ASP.NET UpdatePanel: Is there an UpdatePanel alternative that doesn't send a lot of viewstate or require clientside binding?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, viewstate

Personally, I like doing all my control binding on the server (eg, populating/binding dropdowns, filling textboxes, etc).  When the page loads, I will call BindControls() that binds all controls on the page.  When the user changes a dropdown option inside an UpdatePanel, I will hit the server on a postback and call BindControls() again.

The problem is that UpdatePanels apparently pass the page's entire viewstate back and forth rather than just the viewstate of controls within the UpdatePanel.  I don't understand why this is, but it's a pretty big performance hit as far as speed is concerned.

In the past, I've used Telerik's RadAjaxManager which allowed you to specify which controls' viewstates you wish to be passed to the server.  It was perfect because it required no client-side code and still allowed you to consolidate all your binding logic on the server while keeping viewstate transfer small.

Don't get me wrong:  I love AJAX, Json, and javascript, but I don't like performing binding operations with it.  That said, I'd like to find a way to perhaps configure the UpdatePanel so that it only transfers the viewstate for specific controls or find an alternative control that will still allow me to bind my controls on the server and then deliver updated HTML to the client.

Comment: Is there a reason other than licensing that you would not want to use RadAjaxManager?  It sounds like it was meeting your needs pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be in control, I'd suggest to use jquery + page methods or web services instead. I've been using UpdatePanels and various similar controls in the past, but I've dropped it for reasons like this. It's by far easier to work with jquery than to learn the tricks for updatepanels etc, to achieve the behavior and performance you need. Every layer of abstraction adds an overhead, no matter how great you know the technology.

Comment: Unfortunately, page methods and web services require static methods.  I need to access the controls within an instance of the page that contains the controls I wish to update.  Otherwise, page methods and web services are great for retrieving data and returning JSON objects.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin, there are pretty much no limits when it comes to ajax. Asp.net ajax controls must use JS in the background, so it's definitely feasible. I don't see that as a problem, manipulating objects like this is a fairly common scenario. Don't know your exact issues and needs, so I'm afraid I can't offer any concrete solution.

Comment: They are not only good for retrieving data, web services allow you to better separate the concerns of your UI from your application layer.  This also provides you greater reuse of logic between multiple clients, such as a mobile app or desktop client. You can also control the state of your application and a user's session better in a service than by sending it back and forth in every request / response.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when dealing with ASP.net it's tough to cleanly control how ViewState is ping-ponged to and from your server.  So much of the Page lifecycle is built around ViewState and it's pretty central to the platform as a whole.

Like walther said, the best alternative would be to use a combination of jQuery and web services to handle AJAX functionality on your site.  I would probably steer clear of implementing the functionality as Page methods, as I believe that calling them requires you put the page through the entire lifecycle each time.  I would also recommend looking into using  [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) and [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) to help with databinding to your client-side elements.  When combined properly, these technologies can help you create richer client-side functionality, with greater performance and lower maintenance overhead than using traditional ASP.net AJAX controls.

Another benefit to adopting these more open standards is that they translate much easier to other web platforms.  Using jQuery to handle your AJAX means a lot of the techniques you'd use to create client-side functionality would more or less be the same if you ever needed to develop for a site running PHP or MVC (if you ever wanted to get off of the heavyweight WebForms platform)